# How to hold down a key?

Tags: vb.net

Could you please tell me the code to make the shift key be held for a while and then released? I tried to use Sendkeys.Send ("+"), but it only pushes it once, and I'd like it to hold for about 3 seconds and then release. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Never post an image of code.  It will attract down votes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16343101/832052

Comment: Based on your other comment below, it sounds like you only need to check the Shift key when you are mousing down.  That's a different question.

Comment: If you un-accepted Poat's answer because it doesn't fit your needs then you should add a comment explaining why not, so that he can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may have already been answered here:

[How to simulate held down keys with VB.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401497/how-to-simulate-held-down-keys-with-vb-net-or-c)

They do mentioned that DoEvents may not be the best thing to do in a loop like so, here is an alternative approach: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22634280/Holding-a-key-down-my-code-not-working-VB-NET.html

and in case the link dies:
If you want to simulate a "real" keyboard sleep, I would then go with system settings for keyboard delay/speed. THis can be done with SystemParametersInfo API

```
Const SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY = 22
Const SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED = 10

Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias _
    "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, _
    ByRef lpvParam As Integer, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer


Private Sub HoldKeyDown(ByVal key As Byte, ByVal durationInSeconds As Integer)
    Dim targetTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now().AddSeconds(durationInSeconds)
    Dim kb_delay As Integer
    Dim kb_speed As Integer

    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY, 0, kb_delay, 0)
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED, 0, kb_speed, 0)

    While targetTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now()).TotalSeconds > 0
        keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 0, 0) ' Up key pressed
        keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 2, 0) ' Up key released
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(kb_delay + kb_speed)
    End While

End Sub
```

Not sure if this'll work, seems it's just pressing the key a bunch - I've not had a chance to test this

Comment: Neat solution, however be advised that [**`keybd_event()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) is officially deprecated and replaced by [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), so the former might get removed some time in the future.

Comment: I have made an object-oriented library (called `InputHelper`) that uses the latest functions to simulate input (`InputHelper.Keyboard` utilizes `SendInput`). I haven't taken the time to make a proper documentation for it yet, but the code and release files includes XML comments that are automatically shown by Visual Studio's IntelliSense while you're coding. -- **Link** (with a short explanation): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420637/3740093

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. You may have to format it to even seconds as well.

```
Private Sub HoldDown()
    Dim dt As DateTime = Now
    Do Until Now = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 3, dt)
        SendKeys.Send("+")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Of course, I cannot think of any practical reason why you would want to do this.

Comment: I'm doing a program that clicks on specific places, like an autoclicker with coordinates. But at any given time, I need it to click holding the shift key in a location. And I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Google "Visual Studio SendKeys". First Link. Bottom of the page. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)